# how to add single quotes in a string

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code for adding the singles quotes for a string

```
$gpids=implode("','",array_unique($groupIds));
```

My output coming like these
156','155','161','151','162','163
I want my output like these
'156','155','161','151','162','163'
please help me

Comment: To be simple, add an `echo "'";` before and after implode statement

Comment: [Simple string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php): `$gpids = "'" . implode("','",array_unique($groupIds)) . "'";`

Answer (score 7):

Using concatenation operator

```
$gpids = "'".implode("','",array_unique($groupIds))."'";
```

Comment: Number 1, echoing out single quotes will not concatenate to the string $gpids.

Answer (score 4):

Just concate quote :

```
<?php
$gpids="'" . implode("','",array_unique($groupIds)) . "'";
echo $gpids;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

Simple one:

```
$string = "'" . implode("','",array_unique($groupIds)) . "'";
```

Second one:

```
function add_quotes($str) {
    return sprintf("'%s'", $str);
}

$string =  implode(',', array_map('add_quotes', array_unique($groupIds)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query=$key.'='."'$value'".',';
```

Here $value will have single quotes.